# zf2 get the JSON value in the controller

Tags: jquery, json, zend-framework2

I'd like to know how i can get the json value in the zf2 controller.

My json function:

```
$(".bajaAlumno").click(function () {
    var dat =$(this).attr('id');
    var response = '{"name":"' + dat + '"}';
    alert(response);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'bajaAlumnos',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(response),
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
})
```

And i try this:

```
//module.config.php
'strategies' => array(
    'ViewJsonStrategy',
),
```

And in the controller:

```
public function bajaAlumnosAction()
{
     $request = $this->getRequest();
     die(var_dump($request->isPost()));
     //this is equals FALSE
}
```

What i do wrong?

add in i tries this

```
die(var_dump($this->getRequest()->getContent());
die(var_dump(var_dump($request->getPost()->toArray())));
```

and the same result array(0) , please help

Comment: You not need to stringify JS object. Pass an object to data: `data: {name: dat}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this tutorial:
[Returning JSON from a ZF2 controller action](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/)

And try this in your controller:

```
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel
public function bajaAlumnosAction()
{
     $request = $this->getRequest();
     $result = new JsonModel($request->getPost()->toArray());
     return $result;
}
```

Comment: yes, view send To Controller, and in the controller get back that information.

Comment: thanks , so the var_dump($result) doesnt return the JSON value return this          object(Zend\View\Model\JsonModel)#226 (8) { ["captureTo":protected]=> NULL ["jsonpCallback":protected]=> NULL ["terminate":protected]=> bool(true) ["children":protected]=> array(0) { } ["options":protected]=> array(0) { } ["template":protected]=> string(0) "" ["variables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["append":protected]=> bool(false) }

Comment: you don't need to var_dump for return json to browser. but if you want to see posted data use `var_dump($request->getPost()->toArray())` only.

Comment: it`s give me array(0) { }

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = \Zend\Json\Json::decode ($this->getRequest ()->getContent ());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` in your controller when using Ajax.

Comment: this is the  answer bool(false)